# Prove a set of continuous function is bounded.

Tags: analysis

Let $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ denote the space of all bounded, continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} → \Bbb C$. Let $C_0(\mathbb{R})$
denote the set of continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \Bbb C$ for which
lim $f(x) = 0$ as $x\to\pm \infty$.

a) Prove that every $f ∈ C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is bounded.

So I need to show $|f| < M$ for some $M$.

b) Prove that $C_0(R)$ is closed in $C_b(R)$

I just really need help.  I don't know how to show these two things.

I know that $d$ makes $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ into a complete metric space.  That's the only Theorem from class I really have.

Comment: hint: On large closes balls $f$ is bounded. Can you use the decay of $f$ to zero to show that the function is small far outside?

Comment: Yes the $f:R->C$ and I'm not sure what the decay of f to zero is.  Haven't learned that.

Comment: hint on b: can you show that any sequence in $C_0$ that converges uniformly to some $f$ is again in $C_0$?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ as $x\to\pm \infty$ means that $f$ decays to zero

Comment: mean of $C$ is $\mathbb{C}$(complex number?)

Comment: Yes, I mean the complex numbers.

Comment: Did you lose your interest on this question?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ tends to zero as $|x|\to \infty$, there exist $R_0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq 1$ for every $|x|\geq R_0$. Due to compactness of $[-R_0,R_0]$ we find that $f$ is bounded there by a constant $M$. Thus $\|f\|_\infty\leq \max\{M,1\}$

Let $f_k \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ be given and such that $f_k\to f$ uniformly (i.e. in $C_b(\mathbb{R})$. This is an assumption! If $f$ turns out to be in $C_0$, we have shown that $C_0$ is closed in $C_b$ by definition. We need to show that $f(x)=0$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

For every large enough $|x|$ and some fixed $k$, we find the estimate $$|f(x)|\leq |f(x)-f_k(x)| +|f_k(x)| \leq  \varepsilon$$
The first term in the middle is small due to the uniform convergence, the second term tends to zero for fixed $k$.

@ OP: Can you give the precise argument here?

Comment: I think you used the wrong norm in (2), but I don't see big changes.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I simply want to show that the uniform (here the supnorm enters) limit $f$ of $f_k$ is again in the $C_0$

Comment: For the last statement you can use $|f (x)| \leq |f_k(x) - f(x)| + |f_k(x)|$. For some fixed large enough $k$.

Comment: How did we get $f_k -> f$ uniformly?

Comment: @ John: I also thought about putting this in, but rejected the idea first. But due to you comment I finally changed my answer

Comment: @user201483 That's an assumption. Convergence in the metric on $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is precisely uniform convergence in the standard analytic sense. So we are taking some arbitrary sequence in the subspace which converges in the large space and showing that its limit is in fact in the subspace, which is enough to show that it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem a) is easy.

Ad b): I'm assuming that your distance $d$ is defined by $d(f,g):=\sup_{-\infty<x<\infty}|f(x)-g(x)|$. Consider a function $f_0\in C_b\setminus C_0$. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ with $|x_n|\to\infty$ $\>(n\to\infty)$ and $|f_0(x_n)|\geq 2\epsilon$ for all $n\geq1$.

Now the set 
$$\bigl\{g\in C_b\>\bigm|\>d(g,f_0)<\epsilon\bigr\}$$
is a neighborhood of $f_0$ that does not intersect $C_0$.